# How to register variable in Ansible loop?

Tags: ansible

I have the following loop. I'm trying to get the current server from a list of servers:

```yaml
- name: "Checking LB status"
  loop: "{{ lb_response.json.load_balancer.targets }}"
  when: "item.server.id | string == server_id.content"
  register: current_lb_status
```

However, this give the following error:

```
ERROR! no module/action detected in task.

The offending line appears to be:

    - name: "Checking LB status"
      ^ here
```

In my case, I don't want to take an action when I find this item. I just want to register the result.

(Actually, I am trying to write a playbook which performs this action, in a loop, until `current_lb_status` is unhealthy. So if I'm not on the right path then I'm interested in the feedback!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set_fact` is the module to register a variable.

So, you could, possibly do something like:

```yaml
- name: Checking LB status
  set_fact: 
    targeted_lb: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lb_response.json.load_balancer.targets }}"
  when: "item.server.id | string == server_id.content"
```

---

A loop, here, would be an overkill, though, since you could access it right away, using the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr).
So, registering it in one go:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    targeted_lb: >-
      (
        lb_response.json.load_balancer.targets
          | selectattr('server.id', '==',  server_id.content | int)
      ).0
```

---

*Side note*: you haven't told us which cloud provider you are using, but, chances are that there is already module to do what you are looking for:

- [`community.aws.elb_classic_lb_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/elb_classic_lb_info_module.html)
- [`azure.azcollection.azure_rm_loadbalancer`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_loadbalancer_module.html)
- [`google.cloud.gcp_compute_backend_service module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_backend_service_module.html) / [`google.cloud.gcp_compute_forwarding_rule module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_forwarding_rule_module.html)
- ...

---

And for your actual goal, the `until` loop can well be incorporated in the call to the module giving your information about your load balancers:

```yaml
- name: Query the existing load balancer
  meta: noop 
  # ^-- replace this with the actual module giving you the load balancer info
  # might it be an `uri` module or an actual module of one of the providers
  register: lb_response
  until: >-
    (
      lb_response.json.load_balancer.targets
        | default([])
        | selectattr('server.id', '==',  server_id.content | int)
    ).0 is defined
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! I'm using Hetzner and their module doesn't quite do the right thing :/ My workaround, and what I'm trying to do, is:

1. Fetch the LB status from hetzner's API
2. Find the server status for the particular server which is being deployed
3. Wait until the status == unhealthy (meaning, the LB is no longer sending traffic)

Then I will deploy the new code to the server.